# What does this anonymmous split function do?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

```
narcoticsCrimeTuples = narcoticsCrimes.map(lambda x:(x.split(",")[0], x))
```

I have a CSV I am trying to parse by splitting on commas and the first entry in each array of strings is the primary key.
I would like to get the key on a separate line (or just separate) from the value when calling `narcoticsCrimeTuples.first()[1]`

My current understanding is 'split x by commas, take the first part of each split [0], and return that as the new x', but I'm pretty sure that middle part is not right because the number inside the [] can be anything and returns the same result.

Comment: This expression `narcoticsCrimes.map(lambda x:(x.split(",")[0], x))` is invalid.  You can do something like this `map(function, "comma,separated".split(","))`   - But your question is not stating that.

Comment: Is `narcoticsCrimes` a custom object?  Does it have its own `map` method defined?

Comment: @JordanBonitatis PySpark. It's an RDD

Comment: Thank you for the help so far. I don't understand the first two comments. the expression works as is. moving the x outside the lambda as so renders it invalid: narcoticsCrimes.map(lambda x:(x.split(",")[0]), x)

Comment: What is narcoticsCrimes[0], and what do you want ..Tuples[0] to be?

Comment: The first comment is wrong, ignore it. The second comment is alluding to that the function returns a 2-tuple with the first part (before a comma) and the input as a whole (e.g. `'a,b,c'` --> `('a', 'a,b,c')` which I'm unclear if you really want.

Comment: @SenthilKumaran The syntax is fine. Please see the pyspark tag. Your `map()` function is incorrect in this case

Comment: If you are processing a CSV, why not just use the `csv` module? And for pyspark, there are [excellent support modules that let you process CSV natively](https://github.com/seahboonsiew/pyspark-csv).

Answer (score 1):

Your variable is named "narcoticsCrimeTuples", so you seem to be expected to get a "tuple".

Your two values of the tuple are the first column of the CSV `x.split(",")[0]` **and** the entire line `x`.

> I would like to get the key on a separate line

Not really clear why you want that...

> (or just separate) from the value when calling narcoticsCrimeTuples.first()[1]

Well, when you call `.first()`, you get the entire tuple. `[0]` is the first column, and `[1]` would be the corresponding line of the CSV, which also contains the `[0]` value.

---

If you `narcoticsCrimes.flatMap(lambda x: x.split(","))`, then all the values will be separated.

For example, in the word count example...

```
textFile.flatMap(lambda line: line.split()).map(lambda word: (word, 1))
```

Comment: Your answer and Amir's helped! I ended up using

narcoticsCrimeTuples = narcoticsCrimes.map(lambda x:(x.split(",")[1:], x))
narcoticsCrimeTuples.first()

Comment: Seems pointless. You still have the entire line of the CSV data

Comment: oops meant narcoticsCrimeTuples = narcoticsCrimes.map(lambda x:(x.split(",")[1:])) That's better right?

Comment: The parenthesis aren't doing anything around the split method in that case. It's still not clear why you are trying to remove only one column, but if that gives you what you want, then great

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the syntax seems like you are in PySpark. If that's true you're mapping over your RDD and for each row creating a `(key, row)` tuple, the key being the first element in a comma-separated list of items. Doing `narcoticsCrimeTuples.first()` will just give you the first record.

See an example here:
https://gist.github.com/amirziai/5db698ea613c6857d72e9ce6189c1193